# Simple JavaScript IBAN Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, iban

I wanted to make a really easy JavaScript validation for the IBAN.
It is for a project on school what means the goal of the validation isn't to get a 100% good IBAN validation but something easy to get along with.

I tried to create my own:`/^[A-Z]{2}+[0-9A-Z]*$/`

But apparently it seems to disactivate all the Javascript in the same file.
What is the reason that this disactivates all my JavaScript, and what is a good validation?

The conditions of the validation (might it not be clear already):

1. The first two characters must be alphabetic and upper-case.
2. The other characters can be numeric and/or alphabetic.

The length doesn't have to be included because that is checked with another if-statement in my function.

Comment: If you say, that there is something disabling your js, there must be errors in console. Could you share the relevant parts of the code here?

Comment: Try this:

    [a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{7}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16}

Comment: @Artyom Neustroev that was the catch (probably the wrong word to use), there wasn't an error connected to it.

Comment: @the below code It seems to give the same reaction as mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using two-quantifiers side-by-side

```
/^[A-Z]{2}+[0-9A-Z]*$/
      //  ^ Remove this. It means match the previous token one or more times
```

So, it would be `/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9A-Z]*$/`